# How to make a timer starting from 20 to 0 and running forever?

Tags: javascript, php, timer, counter

What I mean is when I start the timer from 20seconds, then close the browser the timer continues running in the background and when I open it again the timer would be like 10seconds till 0 then repeated again from 20seconds, do that forever.

I've written this code in js but the problem is the code is running in the client side which means when I exit and enter again the timer will start from 20 again.

```
 <p id="demo"></p> 
    <script>
    var rtime = 4;
    const irtime = 4; // initial time for resetting  
    
        function rF(){
            setTimeout(() => {
            var x = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = rtime;
            if(rtime > 0){
                rtime-- ;
                rF();
            }else{
                rtime = irtime;
                rF();
            }
            }, 1000);
        }
        rF();
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can store the previous time in [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), then, on page load, retrieve the time and assign it to `rtime`:

```js
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
  var rtime = localStorage.getItem("last-time");
  const irtime = 4; // initial time for resetting  
  rtime = !rtime ? 4 : rtime;

  function rF() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      var x = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = rtime;
      if (rtime > 0) {
        rtime--;
        rF();
      } else {
        rtime = irtime;
        rF();
      }
      localStorage.setItem("last-time", rtime)
    }, 1000);
  }
  rF();

</script>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Spectric/h8kgjo5d/